# Capture video and audio using javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, firefox, ffmpeg, webrtc

I am trying to capture video and audio from web browser and upload it to the server. The thing is I don't want to use flash in this.

So I am using HTML5 feature and a library called [RecorderRTC](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RecordRTC) to make it possible. I am using Ruby on Rails in backend. Though I am feeling this feature is still under implementation I am facing challenges.

Following javascript code I have written : http://pastebin.com/KjwunFfD and here is my rails code :

```
    uuid = UUID.generate
    audio_file_name = "#{uuid}.wav" if params[:chrome]
    audio_file_name = "#{uuid}.ogg" if params[:firefox]
    video_file_name = "#{uuid}.webm"

    directory = "#{Rails.root}/public/record"
    directory = directory + "/chrome" if params[:chrome]
    directory = directory + "/firefox" if params[:firefox]

    audio_path = File.join(directory, audio_file_name)
    video_path = File.join(directory, video_file_name)
    #puts params[:audioBlob].tempfile.read
    File.open(audio_path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:audioBlob].tempfile.read) }           if params[:audioBlob]
    File.open(video_path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:videoBlob].tempfile.read) }           if params[:videoBlob]

    output = `ffmpeg -i #{video_path} -i #{audio_path} -acodec copy -vcodec copy #{directory}/#{uuid}.mkv`

    message[:video_url] = "/record/chrome/#{video_file_name}" if params[:chrome]
    message[:video_url] = "/record/firefox/#{video_file_name}" if params[:firefox]

    message[:audio_url] = "/record/chrome/#{audio_file_name}" if params[:chrome]
    message[:audio_url] = "/record/firefox/#{audio_file_name}" if params[:firefox]

    message[:audio_video_url] = "/record/chrome/#{uuid}.mkv" if params[:chrome]
    message[:audio_video_url] = "/record/firefox/#{uuid}.mkv" if params[:firefox]
```

My problem is when I try to run this code through Firefox ffmpeg is giving error of codec not found. I am not sure what I am missing. Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your FFMpeg does not support the ogg input supplied with Firefox clients. Have you run the ffmpeg command from the terminal without errors?

I don't think this is related to rails, javascript and so on but only to ffmpeg. Check here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide